# Is there any need to use meta tag to index site's pages

Tags: html

Is there any need to write

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="index,follow">
```

on every site's page which I want to be indexed or is it the default behavior anyway?

Comment: All the HTML files are indexed by default, so you don't have to use this piece of code. If you want to disable indexing by robots, then I'd suggest to use robots.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired behavior is index & follow then you can omit it from your pages based on recommendations from the Google Webmaster guides, and other bots.  As their default behavior is to index & follow links in your content.

Should you want different behavior, it would be good to include this tag, as well as using the Robots.txt if you are looking to completely prevent an item from being indexed.